# Curl works in postman but doesn't work in php code

Tags: php, curl

I'm developing a service for sending otp by sms. The phone company sent the following curl which I imported into Postman (method POST):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "X-Token: <token>" 
-F payloadSend="{ \"alias\": \"<alias>\", \"startDate\": null, 
\"endDate\": null, \"period\": null, \"recurrencesNumber\": null, 
\"recurrencesInterval\": null, \"validityPeriod\": null, \"sentNotify\": 
false, \"deliveredNotify\": false, \"msisdnToNotify\": null,\"sr\": false, 
\"campaignChannel\": { \"channelName\": \"UCP\", \"zone\": null, 
\"zoneType\": null, \"collectionTime\": null }, \"campaignMessage\": { 
\"messageType\": null, \"messageContent\": \"<testo>\", 
\"template\": null, \"file\": \"string\", \"msisdn\": \"<msisdn>\", 
\"listMsisdn\": null, \"fileMsisdn\": \"null\", \"name\": null, 
\"surname\": null, \"extra\": null, \"status\": \"string\", \"delivered\": 
\"string\" } };type=application/json" "https://channel-ssc.api.services.smb.telecomitalia.it/channels/UCP/campaigns?destination
=msisdn&message=static&delivery=immediate&type=single&mo
de=fast" --trace-ascii -
```

In postman everything works correctly and the sms arrives on my mobile device.
I used the tool in postman to create the code in Curl PHP (Code snippet):

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://channel-sscapi.services.smb.telecomitalia.it/channels/UCP/campaigns?destination=msisdn&message=static&delivery=immediate&type=single&mode=fast',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('payloadSend' => '{ "alias": "<alias>", "sentNotify":false, "deliveredNotify": false, "sr": false, "campaignChannel": { "channelName": "UCP" }, "campaignMessage": {"messageContent": "TEST TEST TEST!","msisdn": "<telephon number>"} }'),
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
'X-Token: <token>'
),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

When I run the page I get an error:
**{"timestamp":"2022-08-18T19:53:14.574+00:00","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"","path":"/restful/channels/UCP/campaigns"}**

If I change the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS with this array (=> with :)

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('payloadSend: { "alias": "<alias>", "sentNotify":false, "deliveredNotify": false, "sr": false, "campaignChannel": { "channelName": "UCP" }, "campaignMessage": {"messageContent": "TEST TEST TEST!","msisdn": "<telephon number>"} }'),
```

The error is:
**{"timestamp":"2022-08-18T20:14:45.613+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"","path":"/restful/channels/UCP/campaigns"}**

I think the problem is the array in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS but I don't understand how to fix the error. anyone have any ideas?

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: You're passionate JSON object as the payload. Probably that might be the issue. You should be passing array. Read the official documentation for implementation.

Comment: cURL should automatically set the Content-Type to multipart/form-data, if you pass an array for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. What happens when you remove it from CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER?

Comment: I have already tried that. I left only the X-Token key in the header but the result is the same. The errors are reported in my previous post... 
Why does it work in postman?